# Connect to MSSQL dataBase in Web2Py DAL using pyodbc, hidden username/pw

Tags: python, sql-server, web2py, pyodbc

Have not found a satisfactory answer to this despite much googling. I am also new to web2py and  SQL Server in general, so perhaps I have approached this problem in the wrong way from the start and there is a better solution outside what I have already set up. Anyway:

I am moving a web2py app from one MSSQL Server connection to another, the wrinkle being that for institutional reasons I should not directly "see" the new connection string, including password etc.

I have gotten around this outside web2py by having the owner hide all the details in a .pyc file that I can run but not see any contents.

```
DATA_CONNECTION = imp.load_compiled('DATA_CONNECTION', 'N:\\location')
cnxn                = DATA_CONNECTION.getMyConnection() #produces a pyodbc connection
```

My question is, how do I get the web2py DAL to accept this same 'cnxn' without entering all the protected information hidden in the .pyc file into the connection string?

This is the connection string I was using before (using my network credentials as the user/pw). The new connection has an explicit username/pw in the .pyc file that I cannot see:

```
db = DAL('mssql://DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER= XXX-011;DATABASE=MyDB;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=yes;migrate_enabled = False')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web2py DAL requires a connection string, not a pyodbc connection object. Perhaps whoever created the current .pyc file that you use can create a new one to return a `DAL` object instead of a pyodbc object.

On the other hand, you might try to convince them that using a .pyc file doesn't really add much security, as there are a number of tools available to decompile .pyc files. Furthermore, once you have the pyodbc object, you might be able to extract the connection string from it anyway. There are better ways to control database access and permissions than trying to obscure the connection string.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up creating the DAL object inside the .pyc file like you suggested. The security concern with .pyc files is still legitimate and I'll have to look into that some more.

Comment: Keep in mind that once you create the DAL object from the .pyc file, you can simply do `db._uri` to read the connection string, so not much security.